# How do you find the matrix of a relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Let $A = \{1,2,3\}$, $B = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and define the relation $R$ from $A$ to $B$ by
$R = \{(1, c), (1, d), (2, b), (2, c), (3, a), (3, b)\}$. Represent $R$ (i) as a digraph and (ii) as a matrix.

I can solve the digraph easily but not sure how to solve the matrix. Any tips?

Comment: Start with the digraph, and then read something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix

Comment: Let the rows of the matrix be labeled row1, row2, row3.  Let the columns of the matrix be labeled colA, colB, colC, colD.  Create a $3\times 4$ matrix with $1$'s in the positions corresponding to a row and column if the corresponding row label is related to the corresponding column label and a $0$ there otherwise.  For instance, in row1 colC you have a $1$ since $(1,c)\in R$ while in row1 colB you have a $0$ since $(1,b)\not\in R$